# Running python scripts programmatically in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I have written a simple python program that allows me to run various windows applications. The code involved in running the applications is quite simple - a couple of samples below.

```
import subprocess
# open a windows application
subprocess.Popen("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe")
# open a third party application
subprocess.Popen("C:\\Program Files\\GIMP 2\\bin\\gimp-2.10.exe")
```

I would like to run my own python applications from this program. I have tried simply passing the path to the .py file from within the program, but I get an error message "is not a valid Win32 application". That makes sense to me, but leaves me none the wiser as to how to do this. I wonder if anyone can suggest how I could open/run a .py file programmatically, from within my python application. Any advice appreciated.

Update:

The answer below does provide a solution that works. For example, if the python file is in the same directory (that is, when the full path is just the name of the python file), the following will work.

```
subprocess.Popen(["python","grid.py"])
```

I am having some problems getting this to work with a longer filepath. But I think that is related to filepaths in general, rather than my original question, so I consider my question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.Popen`, it will call the Python interpreter and provide the path to the script as an argument.

for example (we assumes that the Python interpreter is in your system's PATH):

edit: you may need to escape the backslashes one more time when using them as an argument in `subprocess.Popen`, lets use triple backslashes

```
import subprocess

python_executable = "python"  # or "python3" on some systems
python_script = "C:\\\\DellSilver C-Sync\\\\005 Production Apps\\\\CodeEditor.py"

subprocess.Popen([python_executable, python_script])
```